# Capturar en String el valor elegido de un combobox usando JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Estoy haciendo una app en la que el usuario elije una opción de las que tiene un combobox y que después de elegir todos y apretar "Enviar" se mande a una BBDD. 
Lo que preciso es saber como hago para poder capturar el valor que elije el usuario del combobox en un String para después poder enviarlo a la BBDD. Ejemplo: uno de los combobox es de Estaciones de subterráneo. Al clickearle se despliega una lista con las mismas estaciones y el usuario debe clickear una.
hasta ahora no logre capturar ese valor en particular

```
ObservableList<String> SINOlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Si", "No");
ObservableList<String> abiertascerradaslist = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Abiertas", "Cerradas", "Algunas abiertas");
ObservableList<String> funcionalist = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Funciona", "No funciona", "Parcialmente funcionando");
ObservableList<String> alcohollist = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Disponible", "No disponible", "Expendedor dañado");
ObservableList<String> tapabocaslist = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Todos", "Algunos", "Nadie");
ObservableList<String> listaestaciones = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Plaza de Mayo", "Peru", "Piedras", "Lima", "Saenz Peña", "Congreso", "Pasco", "Alberti", "Plaza Miserere", "Loria", "Castro Barros", "Rio de Janeiro", "Acoyte", "Primera Junta", "Puan", "Carabobo", "San Jose de Flores", "San Pedrito");

@FXML
private Label lblhora;
@FXML
private Label lblDiayMes;
@FXML
private ComboBox PGCBA;
@FXML
private ComboBox estaciones;
@FXML
private ComboBox PSIAU;
@FXML
private ComboBox PSBASE;
@FXML
private ComboBox PE;
@FXML
private TextField audio;
@FXML
private TextField estadodered;
@FXML
private TextField anden;
@FXML
private ComboBox alcohol;
@FXML
private ComboBox tapabocas;
@FXML
private ComboBox TAS;
@FXML
private ComboBox ventiladores;
@FXML
private ComboBox ME;
@FXML
private TextField evasion;
@FXML
private TextField incumplimientos;
@FXML
private TextField observaciones;


@FXML
public void mostrarHora(ActionEvent action) {
    Fecha h1 = new Fecha();

    lblhora.setText(h1.mostrarHora());
    lblDiayMes.setText(h1.mostrarFecha());
}



@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    PGCBA.setItems(SINOlist);
    PSIAU.setItems(SINOlist);
    PSBASE.setItems(SINOlist);
    PE.setItems(abiertascerradaslist);
    alcohol.setItems(alcohollist);
    tapabocas.setItems(tapabocaslist);
    TAS.setItems(funcionalist);
    ventiladores.setItems(funcionalist);
    ME.setItems(funcionalist);
    estaciones.setItems(listaestaciones);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el valor seleccionado en el `ComboBox` simplemente usa el mètodo [getValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#getValue--), ejemplo:

```
String valorSeleccionado = comboBox.getValue();
```